# Using twilio to send video SMS

Tags: android, parsing, sms

Cannot get Twilio to send video with SMS using our Parse account. Part of our Android app protocol. Don't know if it's a Parse issue, or twilio.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What have you tried so far, and what errors are you getting?

Comment: Can you share code, please?